# MVC controllers with same name with areas but finds "Multiple types"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have myself a little problem with areas and controllers.
I have a controller called "HomeController" this is the default controller, I then added a new area called "Supplier", I then copied over my HomeController and removed all the methods I don't want to edit and just edited my Index method.

Now when I build it works fine but when I go to my home controller as a supplier it comes up with this error

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can 
happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') 
does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. 
If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 
'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
TestProject.Controllers.Home
TestProject.Areas.Supplier.Controllers.Home
```

I have updated my areas like so

This is my default area

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "TestProject.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
```

And here is my area route file

```
public class SupplierAreaRegistration: AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Supplier";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {

            context.MapRoute(
                "SupplierHomeIndex",
                "Home/Index/{id}",
                defaults: new { area = "Supplier", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "TestProject.Areas.Supplier.Controllers" },
                constraints: new { permalink = new AreaConstraint(AreaName) }
            );

            context.MapRoute(
                "SupplierDefault",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { area = "Supplier", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "TestProject.Controllers"},
                constraints: new { permalink = new AreaConstraint(AreaName) }
            );
        }
    }
```

Can anyone sign some light on this? I have looked at many topics and answers for this via Google and Stackoverflow however nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: update `namespaces: new[] { "TestProject.Controllers" }` in `RegisterRoutes` with `namespaces: new[] { "TestProject.Areas.Supplier.Controllers" }`

Comment: won't that remove my supplier constraints?

Comment: does your action link has area defined? `@Url.Action("action", "controller", new {area = "areaname"})` ?

Comment: I have but it still seems to come up with the same error

Answer (score 1):

You've customized the area's routes and removed the `Supplier` URL prefix. When the routing framework spins up it merely collects all controllers from your application, regardless of where they are, and then looks for a match based on the URL. In your case, you now have two controllers that are both bound to the URL `/Home/*`. Typically, the area's URL would be prefixed with the area's name to avoid the confusion, i.e. `/Supplier/Home`.

Comment: I have updated my route like so

context.MapRoute(
                "SupplierHomeIndex",
                "Supplier/Home/Index/{id}",
                defaults: new { area = "Supplier", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "TestProject.Areas.Supplier.Controllers" },
                constraints: new { permalink = new AreaConstraint(AreaName) }
            );

But still seem to get the "Multiple types" error

Comment: *Both* routes need to be updated. You had this route, plus the area's default route.